# NSOutlineView select with the first click

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I have an NSPanel with a NSOutlineView to display my data. I want to select a row with a first click inside the NSOutlineView even if the panel is not in focus (i.e. not the key window) I have a delegate that allows selection and I have overridden the NSOutlineView class to override the acceptsFirstMouse: method, but I could not get the first click selection.

I checked the mouseDown event and it fired without any problems (in my class that overrides) when the panel was and wasn't the key window. But when the panel is not key, NSOutlineViewDelegate method shouldSelectItem: is not called.

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to subclass your NSTableOutlineView and override:

```
- (BOOL)needsPanelToBecomeKey
```

to return NO.

**NSView class reference states:**

> Overridden by subclasses to determine if the receiver requires its
>   panel, which might otherwise avoid becoming key, to become the key
>   window so that it can handle keyboard input and navigation.
>
> **Discussion**
>
> Such a subclass should also override acceptsFirstResponder
>   to return YES.
>
> This method is also used in keyboard navigation. It determines if a
>   mouse click should give focus to a view (make it first responder).
>   Some views will want to get keyboard focus when you click in them, for
>   example text fields. Other views should only get focus if you tab to
>   them, for example, buttons. You wouldn't want focus to shift from a
>   textfield that has editing in progress simply because you clicked on a
>   check box.

*Source: [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsview_Class/Reference/NSView.html)*